# Excel macro Command button to submit value to a cell

Tags: excel, commandbutton, vba

We have there types of mode Yearly,quarterly,half yearly
I need to program like when we press yearly cell c3 gets value 12 if qauterly is pressed 3,half yrly 6 
Pls help[image: My screen shots]

Answer (score 0):

Makro for button QLY

```
Sub QLY_Click()
 Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "3"
End Sub
```

Makro for button HLY

```
Sub HLY_Click()
 Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "6"
End Sub
```

Makro for button YLY

```
Sub YLY_Click()
 Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "12"
End Sub
```